# Recursion List None Type Returned

Tags: python, list, recursion, types

```
def largestNumber(numberList):

    if len(numberList) == 1:
        return numberList[0]
    else:
        largestNumber(numberList[1:])
```

For this code I am passing in a list, `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]`, and the function returns `None`... but I am expecting it to call itself until it returns `1`. Can someone help explain?

Comment: You need to add `return` to the recursive case, i.e. `return largestNumber(numberList[1:])`  Without it, it's discarding the recursive return value and returning `None` instead.

Comment: plus there is an obvious mistake in your code: it will always return the last value rather than the largest one.

Comment: Also note that once you add the missing return, you will return the last value in the list, so in your example it will be 10.

Comment: Thank to all for the help, this has solved the issue I was having. To Julien, yes, I should of cleaned it up before I submitted but I only needed help with the specific problem.

Comment: Your function only returns something (other than `None`) when the remaining list contains exactly one thing. Just change the last line to `return largestNumber(numberList[1:])`. Recursive functions will generally always need to return something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the last element in each recursion call, and don't forget return the recursion:

```
def largestNumber(numberList):

    if len(numberList) == 1:
        return numberList[0]
    else:
        numberList = numberList[:-1]
        return largestNumber(numberList)

ls = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]


print(largestNumber(ls))
print(ls)

=> 1
=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

Comment: Seriously doubt the OP wants to destroy the list in the process of finding the largest number...

Comment: @martineau you are right, to agresive my method, I updated the answer thanks to you. Thanks for the comment

Comment: Your change may have made it stop purging the list's contents, but it doesn't work. `largestNumber([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10])` returns `1` not `10`—but at least it no longer returns `None`.

Comment: @martineau the OP in the question says return 1, not 10

Comment: You're right...sorry. Unfortunately I can't undo my down-vote unless you make some change to your answer. Do something trivial to it and I will.

Comment: @martineau it's ok... No problem, thanks for helping me make it a better answer. I hope you like it now and up vote

Comment: @Damian I was expecting it to return 1 but It will return 10 that was my own logic error.

Comment: @ccbrantley I'm sorry I'm lost now, do you want to return at the end of all 10 or 1? I mean, did my answer help you? I made an update let me know if that works fine for you

Comment: After talking with you all I realized it will be passing numberList[1:]. This will cause it to return 10 because when we hit our if statement we will be left with a list equal to [10]. I originally was expecting it to return 1 because I had not taken into consideration the values in the list changing places when passed through recursion. Your example helped me, thank you for your time :).

Comment: @ccbrantley you are totally welcome! I have always loved to help! Please don't forget to vote and accept the answer if it was helpful for you :) :D

Answer (score 1):

Something seems to have gone awry in both this question and the accepted answer.  I'm going to try to make sense of it.  No one would write a recursive function just to find the first or last element of a list, and certainly wouldn't name that function `largestNumber()`.

Let's assume the original problem specification was something like:

> Without using `max()`, write a recursive function that emulates `max()`
>   by finding the largest number in a list of numbers.  Called `largestNumber()`, it takes a list and returns a number.

Once the missing `return` is added, the remaining problem with the OP's code, and that of the currently accepted answer, is they throw away elements of the list and simply return the base case of the recursion.  They never compare the current (first) element of the list with the result of the recursion to determine the largest number:

```
def largestNumber(numberList):

    a, *rest = numberList

    if not rest:
        return a

    b = largestNumber(rest)

    return a if a > b else b

if __name__ == "__main__":

    import random

    my_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

    random.shuffle(my_list)

    print(my_list, '->', largestNumber(my_list))
```

**TEST**

```
> python3 test.py
[2, 4, 6, 3, 5, 7, 8, 1, 9, 10] -> 10
> python3 test.py
[6, 4, 9, 1, 10, 7, 5, 3, 8, 2] -> 10
> python3 test.py
[10, 8, 7, 3, 2, 9, 1, 6, 4, 5] -> 10
```